# Filtering ng-repeat against a list in local storage

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, local-storage

I' storing a list of ID's in local storage as a list which I'd like to filter against when loading in a JSON object and looping through the objects in this JSON object with ng-repeat. The idea I have is any items that are being displayed with the ng-repeat, if their ID is in the list then I don't want to display them.

I'm building a notifications page and if the message has been read then I store the id of the notification in local storage, so I can keep track of the notifications that have been read. Then when I get a new JSON object with any new notifications I can check to see which ones in that JSON object have already been read, and then not display them.

I'm not too sure how to filter them with ng-repeat, any ideas?

Thanks

Stephen

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);


myApp.controller("myController1", function($scope) {

  $scope.hideblocked = function(blockedIds) {
    return function(item) {
      return blockedIds.indexOf(item.id) == -1;
    }
  }

  $scope.blockedIds = [1, 5];

  $scope.items = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "a"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "b"
  }, {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "c"
  }, {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "d"
  }, {
    "id": 12,
    "name": "e"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "f"
  }];

  $scope.blockedIds2 = ["1", "5"];

  $scope.items2 = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "a"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "b"
  }, {
    "id": "5",
    "name": "c"
  }, {
    "id": "8",
    "name": "d"
  }, {
    "id": "12",
    "name": "e"
  }, {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "f"
  }];

  $scope.block = function(blockedIds, id) {
    if (blockedIds.indexOf(id) == -1) {
      blockedIds.push(id);
    }

  };


});
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController1">
  If id is a number :
  <span ng-repeat="item in items| filter:hideblocked(blockedIds)">{{item.name}}</span>
  <button ng-click="block(blockedIds,3)">block f</button>
  <br/>If id is a string:
  <span ng-repeat="item in items2| filter:hideblocked(blockedIds2)">{{item.name}}</span>
  <button ng-click="block(blockedIds2,'3')">block f</button>
</div>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```